# DC-DC converter from 5 V input to 6 V with an output current of about 3 A

Tags: voltage-regulator

I wish to make a DC-DC converter from 5 V input to 6 V with an output current of 3 A or thereabouts using a 7806 regulator or similar. Is anyone able to supply me a circuit. A simple circuit would be adequate with component details/values.

I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: 78 series regulators are linear regulators; under no circumstances can they output higher voltage than they're given at the input.

Comment: *I hope that all makes sense.* Not all of it does, a 7806 is a linear regulator, not a switching converter (DCDC) and also not an upconverter (5 V in, 6 V out). *A simple circuit would be adequate* You ask for a circuit so how can you say that a simple circuit is adequate. How would you know? Also we require you to find things yourself first. So what have you found? There are many modules available on Ebay etc.

Comment: Also, you can find lots of power supply reference designs on TI's WEBENCH tool, where you can put your input voltage, and output voltage + current requirements, then it spits out matching designs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you wish with a 7806 this is a linear voltage regulator that requires an input voltage a couple of volts higher than the intended output.

You need to use a boost dc-dc converter. These are widely available pre-built or if you want to build your own several ic manufacturers have online tools where you can enter your supplies parameters and they will produce a design for you (e.g. Texas Instruments webench).